# Is there an option to deactivate the %d (integer placeholder) in Python? I want to use %d for time conversion from string to datetime

Tags: datetime, placeholder

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime.strptime("5/20/2021 05:56:19", '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S')
```

> ValueError: time data '5/20/2021 05:56:19' does not match format '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S'

Comment: Please provide more details to your question. What did you already tried out?

Answer (score 1):

Your date format need to be

```
 datetime.strptime("5/20/2021 05:56:19", '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

i.e. you need to use `%Y` (capital Y instead of y), according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) `%y` is only for interpreting a year using 2 digits. So your issue isn't related to using `%d`